# Can't edit Edit Summary

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, editing, edit-history

I make an edit, and type something in the Edit Summary box. Then I realise five minutes later that my edit summary was wrong. So I click on "edited 5 mins ago", and then on "edit" (with mouse-over text "edit this revision"). So now I can edit my edit. But if I only change the Edit Summary, my change gets lost. Is this a bug?

Test edit 1 (see comments)
Test edit 2 (see comments)

Comment: If it's five minutes ago, the grace period is over. Then if you edit the body, you create a new revision. Thus I wouldn't be surprised that if you try to only change the edit summary, that is intentionally discarded after the grace period. Within the grace period, changing the edit summary alone should work, I think.

Comment: @aniel: Perhaps it was three minutes. But it let me into the edit-editing page. I am about to try it here. Hold on a sec...

Comment: Yes, it is as I thought. The Edit Summary can only be changed if you change something else at the same time.

Comment: Similar question on [MSE](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/96918).

Comment: If it's within 5 minute period, just add  extra space at the end of the question -- this is enough for edit to be recognized, and the edit history entry changed.

Answer (score 8):

This is *kinda* intentional; if you don't change anything, it feels odd to record a change record. Indeed: you can't edit the revision history, but *in the general case*, that is probably a good thing anyway. I'm not sure this is going to cause a real problem very often - or at least, it seems more likely to be misused by changing revision reasons.

As a rule of thumb, I would say:

- if there is something else meaningful to edit, and you *really really* want; make another edit and clarify there
- but otherwise, probably best to just live with what was recorded at the time

Comment: But some of us just hate to leave misprunts lyign aruond.